# What is the event after the chart is completely drawn and animation is finished in ext.js 4

Tags: extjs

I have a tab panel. Each tab has a chart in it. 
I am trying to create a loading mask between each tab switch. 
I have tried to mask the body before render of a chart and unmask afterrender but it seems like the chart is unmasked before the chart is completely drawn.
What happens is i dont even see a loading bar just a white screen than the drawn chart.
(If i put an alert before unmask, i see the loading mask)

The closest i have come is putting the masking on the tab panel`s before change event and unmasking on chart`s afterrender event. Still no luck...
Need help,
Thanks

```
listeners:{
        beforetabchange:function(){
            Ext.getBody().mask("Loading");
        },
        tabchange:function(){
            //Ext.getBody().unmask();
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the mask by listening to specific event on the chart (or its store), not on the tab panel. By example the  `render` event of the chart or the `load` event from its store.